# DIV height 100% not working on large content

Tags: html, css, drupal, height

I am trying to get my background to fill 100%. It currently is on every page except where the content gets too large (see photo (http://i58.tinypic.com/2n18hn8.png)). I have tried a bunch of different things to fix it but nothing is working. If I change the #page-wrapper to 3000px it will display the background fully, but then is too large on other pages. Please help

```
html,
body,
#page  {
height: 100%;
}

#page-wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 960px;
}
```

Comment: post your html so we can see it

Comment: It's in drupal so I don't have html available to post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your body class

```
body{
  background-size:cover;
  background-image: url('img/cover.png');
  background-position: top center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Try this and let me know what you think.

Comment: @Lindsay Jacoby: Let me know if this helped you.

Comment: @LindsayJacoby: Glad to help. Please upvote if you support this answer.